# Is there an algorithm to diagonalize a matrix using gauge transformations

Tags: mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, integrable-systems

I have two matrices $U(\lambda, x,t)$ and $V(\lambda, x,t)$, where $\lambda$ is a parameter, which belong to the $sl(2)$ algebra, and satisfy the zero-curvature equation
$$
\partial_t U - \partial_x V + [U,V] = 0
$$
And I would like to diagonalize $U$ using a local gauge transformation
$$
U \to A = gUg^{-1}+ \left( \partial_x g \right) g^{-1} \tag{1}
$$
Is there an algorithm or formula to achieve this? I tried to Google it, but couldn't find anything,.

---

Motivation:

For integrable field theories, the following quantities can be proven to be conserved in time
$$
I_n(\lambda) = \mathrm{Tr} (T^n(t,\lambda)) 
$$

To answer fs137's question, there is a theorem which states that there exists a gauge transformation which can diagonalize both $U$ and $V$.

The reason why I want to diagonalize the matrix is because the quantities
$$
Q_k(\lambda) = \int\limits_0^L A_k \mathrm{d} x
$$
are the local conserved quantites of the field theory. Where $A$ is the diagonalized matrix (see equation (1)) expressed as formal series in $\lambda$
$$
A = \sum\limits_{r=-n}^\infty A_r \lambda^r
$$

Comment: To be clear, you want the transformed $U$ to be diagonal for all $x$? What information do you have about $U$? (i.e. assumed continuity or differentiability, explicit formulas, analiticity, ... ?) What is the role of $t$? I also imagine the second term is $(\partial_x g)g^{-1}$, but the notation coud use some sprucing up.

Comment: Try to solve the PDE for $g$. Perhaps a cleaner starting question would be, "When is it possible to find a gauge transformation $g$ that diagonalizes $U(x,t)$".

Comment: This seems to depend rather crucially on your gauge group. In any case, diagonalizing U or V seems a rather odd thing to do since you should think of them as abstract elements of the Lie algebra, not concrete matrices in a fixed basis. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I've updated my answer, but I'm afraid my motivation is too difficult to follow unless you are already a bit familiar with integrable models (which is why omitted the motivation to begin with). The matrices belong to the $sl(2)$ algebra.

Comment: Well, as @fs137 points out, this is apparently 4 ODEs, but here is why they are only 3: the *trace* of your fundamental condition above (1) decouples in the commutator, and so decouples, contributing something already diagonal and proportional to the identity. The rest, for traceless 2x2 complex matrices can be recast in terms of  [Pauli vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) with the generic multiplication law
$(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{\sigma})(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{\sigma}) = (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) \, I + i ( \vec{a} \times \vec{b} )\cdot \vec{\sigma} ~.$ Solve for triplet **g**.

Comment: In case it is not self-explanatory, solve $( A_z \sigma_z)(\vec{g} \cdot \vec{\sigma})= (\vec{g} \cdot \vec{\sigma})(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\sigma}) +(\partial_x\vec{g} \cdot \vec{\sigma})$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I think I understand you, but currently I'm working on something else so I don't have time to really try it. I will need it at some point though, so thanks for your answer!